# How to add blank columns using python pandas between current dataset

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, xlsx

I am learning python and I have a python script that is reading an XLSX file that contains multiple columns with various data (below).
data: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ACyTyQYLm-nwylJnLGWrdPJkP9HAizP-/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=115967267417104849318&rtpof=true&sd=true

I am attempting to take the last columns labeled "rndm_tags" and move them from their current location to begin at column X instead of their current column "N" leaving empty columns in between.Any direction or help is appreciated!

Here is what I am attempting currently via the python code with some other things i have tried:

I am reading the header info to get the actual values of the file

```
#Currently in use
#read excel file
  clean = pd.read_excel('test2.xlsx', header=None)
  print("Column headings:")
  print(clean.columns)
  #top = list(clean.columns.values)


  #print(top)

  #remove duplicates
  dedup = clean.drop_duplicates()
  dedup.insert(25, "", [""])
  
  #dedup.to_excel('test3.xlsx', index=False, header=False, columns=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23])
  print("Column headings:")
  print(dedup.columns)

#End of currently in use
```

I am getting these errors:

> Column headings:
> Int64Index([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
> 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24],
> dtype='int64')
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "", line 264, in 
> dedup.insert(25, "", [""])
> File "frame.py", line 4438, in insert
> value = self._sanitize_column(value)
> File ", in _sanitize_column
> com.require_length_match(value, self.index)
> File "common.py", line 557, in require_length_match
> raise ValueError(
> ValueError: Length of values (1) does not match length of index (667)

I am expecting to move the columns from their current location of column's M -W to  X - AG leaving columns M - W empty and open.

#Begin Other Attempts Testing Rearranging columns

```
#  adCol = rd.reindex(columns = rd.columns.tolist() + ["23","24","25","26","27","28","29","30","31","32"])

#  rd.columns(adCol)

#  rd.to_excel('test4.xlsx', header=None, index=False)

# print("Column headings:")
#  print(rd.columns)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for your problem, you can use the `pop()` and `insert()` functions.
Syntax:

```
df.pop('column name')
df.insert('column number(0 for 1st column)', column_name, column_values)
```

Here it is in a program:

```
import pandas as pd

# define data
data = {'Age': [55, 20, 35, 10], 'Name': ['Rohan', 'Ritik', 'Sangeeta', 'Yogesh'],
        'Address': ['Lucknow', 'Delhi', 'Haridwar', 'Nainital'],
        'Phone Number': [123456789, 234567890, 3456789012, 4567890123]}

# create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# print original dataframe
print("Original Dataframe")
print(df)

# shift column 'Name' to first position
first_column = df.pop("Name")
# insert column using insert(position,column_name,
# first_column) function
df.insert(0, 'Name', first_column)

print()
print("After Shifting column to first position")
print(df)
```

Then just clear out the columns between them using `drop()`.
Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks Mini_TD! I'm having some issues while trying to utilize this method. My data index has multiple column names 0-24...I have attempted to use the following:
'''
data2 = dedup.copy()
ToPop = ['13', '14', '15, '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24'] # And tried with dual brackets
'''
in attempt to pop those columns at the end of my file and data to then be able to clear out those original columns data with drop...however, i'm getting that those do not exist in my index? I'm validating that with print the column headings as follows:
(below)

Comment: Continued:
'''
print("Column headings:")
print(data2.columns)
'''
which prints out 0-24 as an int64 index. 
What am I missing here?

Comment: k, i was offline for a while ago, lemme see your problem and I will update you on a solution

Comment: It could be that if the columns are popped, their index is erased, that could be the case for that error, test it without the deleting code, comment it out not delete it, and see if that works
EDIT: By erased I mean their older index is erased, and then it could throw an error as it couldn't find those index values

Comment: The dataset says access denied

Answer (score 0):

Here, try this, is this your expected output? Here I have erased 2 columns Age and name and moved the address and phone number to their positions. First, we need to find indexes and it is the same dataset as earlier, so we use this code:

```
columns_to_replace = ['Age', 'Name']
temp_indexes = []
# We need to get the columns index, so we use the following:
for i in columns_to_replace:
        temp_indexes.append(df.columns.get_loc(i))
print(temp_indexes)
```

And this displays the following output:

```
Original Dataframe
   Age      Name   Address  Phone Number
0   55     Rohan   Lucknow     123456789
1   20     Ritik     Delhi     234567890
2   35  Sangeeta  Haridwar    3456789012
3   10    Yogesh  Nainital    4567890123
[0, 1]
```

Ignore the data frame, I had printed it earlier.

Now we can iterate over these ids to replace and clear the 2 columns. You can use the earlier code to get the index of other columns if you need it.
Now we just pop and replace, as shown here:

```
# After getting these indexes, we shall use them to replace the data.
first_column = df.pop('Address')
second_column = df.pop('Phone Number')
columns_replace_by = ['Address', 'Phone Number']
column_values = [first_column, second_column]

for i in columns_to_replace:
        df[i] = " "
```

Now we have cleared those 2 columns, the final part is replacing them, which can be either done like this:

```
df.insert(temp_indexes[0], columns_replace_by[0], first_column)
df.insert(temp_indexes[1], columns_replace_by[1], second_column)
```

Here is the full program:

```
import pandas as pd

# define data
data = {'Age': [55, 20, 35, 10], 'Name': ['Rohan', 'Ritik', 'Sangeeta', 'Yogesh'],
        'Address': ['Lucknow', 'Delhi', 'Haridwar', 'Nainital'],
        'Phone Number': [123456789, 234567890, 3456789012, 4567890123]}

# create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# print original dataframe
print("Original Dataframe")
print(df)

# shift column Phone number, address to first position
columns_to_replace = ['Age', 'Name']
temp_indexes = []

# We need to get the columns index, so we use the following:
for i in columns_to_replace:
        temp_indexes.append(df.columns.get_loc(i))

# After getting these indexes, we shall use them to replace the data.
first_column = df.pop('Address')
second_column = df.pop('Phone Number')
columns_replace_by = ['Address', 'Phone Number']
column_values = [first_column, second_column]

for i in columns_to_replace:
        df[i] = " "

df.insert(temp_indexes[0], columns_replace_by[0], first_column)
df.insert(temp_indexes[1], columns_replace_by[1], second_column)

print("New df")
print(df)
```